# How to change in photoshop script color of Smart Object Layer, or Rasterized Image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, script

I need to change color of Smart Object Layer in JS script. I found how to change TextLayer, but SmartObjects haven't "textItem" property. Need to change it like Color Overlay works in Photoshop. For example i have this hoodie:
[image]

I have been selected Compass layer right now and I wanna run my JS script. Then compass should change his color to red (or something else). This compass layer is Smart Object Layer (or Rasterized Image).

Can anyone help me with that? I spend 3 days to find how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Can you elaborate on what your desired result is? As it stands it's rather vague. Are you going to want to change the color to a different color down the road? Why does it need to be a script? A little more insight is needed.

Comment: Hi @Ovaryraptor ! The result is should be like that https://i.imgur.com/HJVwxFi.png
It should be a script, because I need to change .psd files on background (e.g. move compass 20px to right side and change color to blue) automatically.

Comment: I still don't see why you need a script for this. Let me clarify, what is your _END GOAL_? Is this going into a catalog, is it a one-off edit, are you going to have to make alignment and color edits in the future for many colors?

Comment: If the only goal is to change the color I think it's better to do an Action.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I have a site with t-shirts and wanna give clients opportunity to customize the t-shirt. I have psd file of t-shirt, and need way to change layers in this file. The only thing which can change it, is Photoshop. And I need change layers in psd file, (like colors, positions) then send it to the printer. And only thing I can't do right now - change color on Smart Object using scripting Photoshop.

Comment: How exactly you want to change SO color?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy By using Blending Options -> Color Overlay. But I find, that Photoshop API hasn't api for this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a Color Overlay effects with a specific color (red in this example). Modify `r`, `g` and `b` values to the ones you need.

```
applyColorOverlay(
{
    r: 255,
    g: 0,
    b: 0,
})

function applyColorOverlay(color)
{
    var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putProperty(charIDToTypeID('Prpr'), charIDToTypeID('Lefx'));
    ref1.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt'));
    desc6.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref1);
    var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc8.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('enab'), true);
    desc8.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID('present'), true);
    desc8.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID('showInDialog'), true);
    desc8.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Md  '), charIDToTypeID('BlnM'), charIDToTypeID('Nrml'));
    var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc9.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('Rd  '), color.r);
    desc9.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('Grn '), color.g);
    desc9.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('Bl  '), color.b);
    desc8.putObject(charIDToTypeID('Clr '), charIDToTypeID('RGBC'), desc9);
    desc8.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Opct'), charIDToTypeID('#Prc'), 100.000000);
    desc7.putObject(charIDToTypeID('SoFi'), charIDToTypeID('SoFi'), desc8);
    desc6.putObject(charIDToTypeID('T   '), charIDToTypeID('Lefx'), desc7);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('setd'), desc6, DialogModes.NO);
};
```